# Google workflow http.get url_encode to Cloud Run function returns 403

Tags: google-workflows

I have a CloudRun function that accepts multiple URL inputs and this works fine via cURL from Google Shell, e.g

`curl https://myapp.a.run.app/function1/input1/input2`

and where input1 is an email address, input2 a string with no spaces, input3 and int and input4 a filename with spaces, e.g

`curl https://myapp.a.run.app/function2/input1/input2/input3/input4`

I have a Cloud worklow that calls this function in a few steps, building up a URL from previous responses. The calls to the function in steps before are working fine, however when I attempt to call the function via a URL where the email address/filename inputs are text.url_encoded prior, the workflow fails with a 403 error.

```
    - step3_assign_input1:
        assign:     
          - step3_URL: '${"https://myapp.a.run.app/function1/" + step2result.body.field1.field2["b:input1"]}'
    - step4_get_input1:
        try:
          call: http.get
          args:
            url: ${step3_URL}
          result: step4result
        retry:
          predicate: ${custom_predicate}
          max_retries: 10
          backoff:
            initial_delay: 2
            max_delay: 60
            multiplier: 2
    - step4a_sleep:
          call: sys.sleep
          args:
              seconds: 5
    - step5_assign_input2:
        assign:
          - step5_URL: '${"https://myapp.a.run.app/function2/" + step4result.body.field1.field2["a:input2"]}'
    - step6_get_input2:
        try:
          call: http.get
          args:
            url: ${step5_URL}
          result: step6result
        retry:
          predicate: ${custom_predicate}
          max_retries: 10
          backoff:
            initial_delay: 2
            max_delay: 60
            multiplier: 2
    - step7a_encode_email:
        call: text.url_encode
        args:
          source: ${args.email}
        result: encode_email
    - step7b_encode_filename:
        call: text.url_encode
        args:
          source: '${step6result.body.field1.field2["a:FileName"]}'
        result: encode_filename
    - step8_assign_emailURL:
        assign:
          - emailURL: '${"https://myapp.a.run.app/email/" + encode_email + "/" + args.type + "/" + args.serial + "/" + encode_filename}'
    - step9_get_emailURL:
        try:
          call: http.get
          args:
            url: ${emailURL}
          result: step9result
        retry:
          predicate: ${custom_predicate}
          max_retries: 10
          backoff:
            initial_delay: 2
            max_delay: 60
            multiplier: 2
    - returnOutput:
        return: ${step9result}

custom_predicate:
  params: [e]
  steps:
    - what_to_repeat:
        switch:
          - condition: ${e.code in [429, 500, 502, 503, 504]}
            return: true
    - otherwise:
        return: false
```

From the workflow logs I can see the URL is being constructed as

`https://myapp.a.run.app/email/someone%40email.com/String/12345678/THIS%20File%20Name%01.pdf`

which if I call via cURL GET in CloudShell it returns with a 200 response code.

In the Workflow logs I get a HTTP server responded with error code 403, and Error: Forbidden\u003c/h1\u003e\n\u003ch2\u003eAccess is forbidden.

```
{
  "insertId": "sl7uy9bd1",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "activityTime": "2023-01-06T05:44:39Z",
    "state": "FAILED",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.workflows.type.ExecutionsSystemLog",
    "failure": {
      "source": "main.step9_get_emailURL, line: 76",
      "exception": "HTTP server responded with error code 403\nin step \"step9_get_emailURL\", routine \"main\", line: 76: {\"body\":\"\\n\\u003chtml\\u003e\\u003chead\\u003e\\n\\u003cmeta http-equiv=\\\"content-type\\\" content=\\\"text/html;charset=utf-8\\\"\\u003e\\n\\u003ctitle\\u003e403 Forbidden\\u003c/title\\u003e\\n\\u003c/head\\u003e\\n\\u003cbody text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff\\u003e\\n\\u003ch1\\u003eError: Forbidden\\u003c/h1\\u003e\\n\\u003ch2\\u003eAccess is forbidden.\\u003c/h2\\u003e\\n\\u003ch2\\u003e\\u003c/h2\\u003e\\n\\u003c/body\\u003e\\u003c/html\\u003e\\n\",\"code\":403,\"headers\":{\"Alt-Svc\":\"h3=\\\":443\\\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\\\":443\\\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\\\":443\\\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\\\":443\\\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\\\":443\\\"; ma=2592000,quic=\\\":443\\\"; ma=2592000; v=\\\"46,43\\\"\",\"Content-Length\":\"235\",\"Content-Type\":\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\",\"Date\":\"Fri, 06 Jan 2023 05:44:38 GMT\",\"X-Appengine-Country\":\"ZZ\"},\"message\":\"HTTP server responded with error code 403\",\"tags\":[\"HttpError\"]}"
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "workflows.googleapis.com/Workflow",
    "labels": {
      "workflow_id": "myworkflow",
      "location": "australia-southeast1",
      "resource_container": "323152299552"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-01-06T05:44:39.101297442Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "workflows.googleapis.com/revision_id": "000036-15c",
    "workflows.googleapis.com/execution_id": "f2175706-7e8a-4321-916b-487231a10d6b"
  },
  "logName": "projects/myproject/logs/workflows.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions_system",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-01-06T05:44:40.026366626Z"
}
```

If I look at the logs of the CloudRun function, I see successful logs from the earlier steps in the workflow. but, no logs from the step that is failing.

Hopefully someone can provide some insight why this fails via a workflow steps.

Comment: Seems like the issue is related to permission. Have you checked this [troubleshooting document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#editor)?

Comment: @RoopaM I invoke the same CloudRun function 3 times in the same workflow in different steps/path and those work, the 4th invocation throws a 403. I've checked the document but can't find anything related. The function is set to "Allow unauthenticated invocations" and "Allow all traffic" but should error on the first step shouldn't it if there was a permission error ?

Comment: Have you tried to send dummy values without special chars like '%40', '%20', '%01', '.pdf'?

Comment: Yes I have. `Works - https://myapp.a.run.app/email/someone@gmail.com/String/12345678/ThisFileName.pdf` and `Fails - https://myapp.a.run.app/email/someone@gmail.com/String/12345678/This File Name.pdf, https://myapp.a.run.app/email/someone@gmail.com/String/12345678/This%20File%20Name.pdf, https://myapp.a.run.app/email/someone%40gmail.com/String/12345678/This%20File%20Name.pdf`

Comment: seems like issue with workflow url, feel free to contact support [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/)